# knife cookbook site search apache2 return error

Tags: chef-infra

```
knife cookbook site search apache2
```

returned

```
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch: Response body length 2175 does not match HTTP Content-Length header 621.
```

Chef: 11.12.8

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that there is still a bug.  There was a similar report that is reported to be fixed in 11.12.0.

- https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5041
- https://github.com/opscode/chef/pull/1329

Likely you should try the suggestions in this Jira:

- Try setting the 'no_lazy_load true' in your client.rb.
- Try setting the 's3_url_ttl' to something higher than the default on your server

If neither of these fix it, you likely need to open a request with Chef on Github providing more context.  It looks like the fix in CHEF-5041 was pretty closely related to a flaw in a particular proxy that was still true to the spec, simply not accounted for in the Chef code.  So your issue may be another edge case.